# Playframework load wrong routes file

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a old play framework project, named `old-project`, with `routes` file

```
    GET     /something    @controller.SomethingController.showMessage()
```

Now, I want to create a new project, named `new-project`. But I want to reuse source code from `old-project`. So `new-project` will use `old-project` as a lib. In `new-project` build.sbt file

```
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.github" %% "old-project" % "2.0"
   )
```

Then I edited routes files in `new-project`

```
   GET     /api/hello    @controller.MyController.hello()
```

Problem is when I tried to start `new-project`, I can use all `old-project` routes but can't use any new route in `new-project/conf/routes`.

When I tried to access `api/hello` then my app return `Action not found`

I guess `new-project` build Router from `old-project/conf/routes` rather than its own. How can I specify routes file for fix my problem?

Comment: Please post the file structure of the project and complete content of route files in both projects.